# Postfix header checks

Tags: email, postfix, regular-expressions

How can I write regex for postfix header check to reject all the mails with `X-Source-Dir` having `abc/def`?

Is this OK?

```
/^X-Source-Dir:\s(.*abc\/def.*)/ REJECT due to spam:
```

---

Thanks a lot Ladadadada:)

But with,

```
/^X-Source-Dir:\s(abc|def)/ REJECT due to spam:
```

all the mails from dir /abc/def would be rejected right.. My requirement is like, reject the mails originating from "/home/user/public_html/templates/beez". I tried the below given header check:

```
/^X-Source-Dir:\s(.\*templates.*|.\*wp-content.\*)/ REJECT The message was rejected due to classification as spam from CMS
```

But the problem is this would also reject mails with source dir as `/home/user/public_html/templatesabc.com/`

Please assist.

Comment: Create a file /etc/postfix/header_checks and refer to http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html

Answer (score 2):

In `main.cf`:

```
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

and in `/etc/postfix/header_checks`:

```
/^X-Source-Dir:\s(abc|def)/ REJECT due to spam:
```

Then reload postfix with `sudo postfix reload`.

The change I made to your regex was to remove the dots and replace the slash with a pipe.